# ClearML Change Debug Samples output destination after moving task to another project and renaming it

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch-lightning, clearml

I start a ClearML Task with .init() and then start my application, which is tracked by the automatic logging.
However, I get my project and task name when the application starts because my application reads a config file that does not exist before the init() call. So I created a temporary task and later moved it to the correct project and renamed the task `task.move_to_project(new_project_name=project_name)` and `task.rename(new_name=task_name)`.
But the debug samples won't be moved to the new project structure and task name.
I found the option to update the output_uri for the model repository with `task.output_uri = folder`, but this only sets the model repository to the new location and not the location for the debug samples.

My questions are

1. How can I dynamically change the location of the debug samples?
2. How can I move existing debug samples to a new location and update existing tasks?

Pseudo code:

```
task = Task.init(project_name='temp_project', task_name='temp_task')
# .. do custom initialization
project_name = read_config('project_name')
task_name = read_config('task_name')

task.move_to_project(new_project_name=project_name)
task.rename(new_name=task_name)

new_output_path = '~/clearml/'
task.output_uri = new_output_path
# TODO (1) change logging directory for debug_samples
```

I am using the latest clearml from pypi and the latest server version. My framework is PyTorch (Lightning). I'm running on Ubuntu.

Thanks.